# salesforce XMLHttpRequest on IE10

Tags: ajax

Salesforce overrides XMLHttpRequest whenever I use IE10. Because of this we can't 
use Jquery File Upload to post files to S3. What could be walk around to this problem? or This is just a simple bug on the salesforce?

```
Sarissa.originalXMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;
XMLHttpRequest = function () {
    if (!_SARISSA_XMLHTTP_PROGID) {
        _SARISSA_XMLHTTP_PROGID = Sarissa.pickRecentProgID(["Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "MSXML2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"]);
    }
    return new ActiveXObject(_SARISSA_XMLHTTP_PROGID);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your, I assume Visualforce, page doesn't use a lot of standard Salesforce functionality, have you tried switch the code around, bringing the `XMLHttpRequest` back to the original one?

```
XMLHttpRequest = Sarissa.originalXMLHttpRequest;
```

Comment: Yes I have tried and it worked